# Extend Workspace on Kali using VMware

Tags: kali-linux

I'm using Kali on Windows via VMware.

The web browser and other things sometimes seem too much zoomed in and I can't get to certain links or buttons.

How do I zoom out or expand the area? 
(clicking maximize doesn't do anything)

Provided is a screen shot to better illustrate what I mean:
[image]

As you can see, I can't get to what's below.
So far I've been managing with the tab key, but it's stressful.

Comment: what happens when you press ctrl alt and enter key?

Comment: nothing :/  - ctrl alt allows me to go back to my original OS

Answer (score 1):

Ok after playing around a LOT, I figured it out.

hold alt and click & drag with the mouse.
It's not a complete solution like a resize, but it'll allow you to see the area below.